# How to make multiple SVGs inline?

Tags: html, svg, inline

I have the source for multiple SVG files in my code but for some reason, they won't go inline, even though on the Google Drawings in which they were made, they were in the exact same line.

```html
The JSFiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/53raccoon/zrym4h95/3/
```

Comment: In your fiddle you have 2 svg elements both visible although to see the second one you need tp scroll. A good idea would be to replace the extremely long path with text. Also if you want to see the svg elements in the same line add a width like this: `svg{width:300px;border:1px solid}`  The border is added to make you see the size of the svg elements and the white space around the green shape.

Comment: @enxaneta doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

You had two problems:

1. By default SVGs have a width of "100%".  If you want them to be inline, you have to give them a smaller width.  Eg. "40%"

   ```
   a {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 40%;
   }
   ```
2. The other proble was that your `viewBox` values were way too big.  You buttons were a lot smaller than what the viewBox said.  For instance, the first viewBox

   ```
   viewBox="0.0 0.0 960.0 720.0"
   ```

   should be more like

   ```
   viewBox="184 27 203 76"
   ```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9n68bvem/)